# checkbox на картинках

Tags: html, css, css3, checkbox

В форме нужно сделать подобный checkbox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это лучше реализовать, есть идея подобного:

```
    input[type="checkbox"]
   {
    display:none;

  }
  input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 41px;
  }

  label{
    margin: 0;
    color: @gray4;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"] + label::before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: @blue1 no-repeat center center;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }


  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-image: url('../img/checked.png');
  }
```

То есть основная идея на псевдоклассе `before`, однако хочется узнать как лучше?

Comment: С инпутом и псевдоэлементом норм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлементов. JavaScript не нужен, он будет здесь избыточным. И для таких `checkbox` не обязательно грузить изображение, можно полностью сделать на стилях:

```css
.wrapper{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.checkbox{
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.checkbox img{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
}
.checkbox span{
  margin:5px;
  display:block;
}
.checkbox label{
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}
.checkbox label:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:75px;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-radius:50px;
}
.checkbox label:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:26px;
  height:12px;
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:88px;
  border-left:5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]{
  display:none;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
  background-color:#8dc3ff;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after{
  border-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="checkbox">
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">
  <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
  <span>Текст текст</span>
</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox2">
<label for="checkbox2">
  <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
  <span>Текст текст</span>
</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox3">
<label for="checkbox3">
  <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
  <span>Текст текст</span>
</label>
  </div>
</div><!--.wrapper-->
```